# Swift における Tab 間での関数の呼び出しについて

Tags: swift, xcode

UITabBarController の異なるタブ間で関数を呼び出す方法について質問です。
UITabBarController で FirstViewController, SecondViewController を作成したのですが、FirstView のボタンを押すことで SecondView の関数を呼び出すにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

protocol を介して delegate を設定してやることによってできそうなのですが、以下のようなコードを実行してもうまく出力されませんでした。

FirstViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //print("first view generated")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    weak var delegate: Del?
    @IBAction func say(sender: AnyObject) {
        //print("button pushed")
        self.delegate?.sayHello()
    }
}


@objc protocol Del {
    func sayHello() -> Void
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, Del {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //print("second view generated")
    //self.sayHello()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func sayHello() -> Void{
        print("hello world");
    }
}
```

（tab を切り替えて first, second ともに生成したのちにボタンを押してもコンソールに"hello world"が出力されない。）

delegate を扱っているコードを見ると SecondView の中で FirstView をインスタンス化して delegate を self に指定すればよさそうなのですが、この場合どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController`のタブを固定している（動的にタブを変更しない）ことを前提にしますと、`UITabBarController`のプロパティ`viewControllers`を使って、`FirstViewController`から`SecondViewController`をたどっていくことができますので、Delegateの出番は必要ありません。`UIViewController`のプロパティ`tabBarController`で、`UITabBarController`のインスタンスを取得し、`UITabBarController`のプロパティ`viewControllers`から、`SecondViewController`のインスタンスを取得します。

*FirstViewController*

```
@IBAction func say(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let controller = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? SecondViewController {
        controller.sayHello()
    }
}
```

ここで注意していただきたいのは、`UITabBarController`のインスタンスをロードした直後は、Viewがロードされているのは、最初の（いちばん左のタブの）View Controllerだけだという点です。つまり、`SecondViewController`のインスタンスは生成されていますが、`loadView`メソッドが実行されていないので、ラベルなどのViewにアクセスすると、`nil`が返ってきます。

```
@IBAction func say(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let controller = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? SecondViewController {
        controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
        controller.label?.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

ラベルなどのViewにアクセスする場合は、上のサンプルのように、`loadViewIfNeeded()`メソッドを呼んで、Viewをロードしておきます。

Comment: ご回答いただいた通りにしたところ解決いたしました。tabBarContorollerのプロパティからインスタンスにアクセスできるならば確かにdelegateは必要なかったですね（ようやくView間のつながりが理解できました）。これからsecondViewのラベル等もいじる予定でしたのでloadViewIfNeededもここで教えていただいてありがたかったです。どうもありがとうございました。